# Preencher ValidationSummary com erros dos Data Annotations em Submit por AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Defini diversos *DataAnnotations* para o modelo o qual o form instancia.

Quando o submit do Form não é por AJAX tudo funciona como deveria, ou seja, o *ValidationSummary* é preenchido com os `ErrorMessage` definidos nas minhas classes.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema é quando realizo o submit do form de forma assíncrona com o jquery.

Realizo o Submit do form da seguinte forma:

```
$.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("CriarEvento")',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: $(this).serialize() + '?preco=' + preco,                        
                    success: function (obj) {                            
                        if (obj.success == true) {
                            alert('evento salvo com sucesso');
                            $('#fecharCrEvento').click();
                            $('#calendario').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                        }
                        else {

                        }

                    }
                }).
```

Como posso usar a mesma validação definida nos DataAnnotations antes mesmo do submit do form? De tal forma que o `ValidationSummary` seja preenchido com os erros

E sim, estou validando o model no Controller também.

Answer (score 1):

Para verificar isso, utilize o código abaixo:

```
if ($("#idForm").valid())
{
           $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("CriarEvento")',
                type: 'POST',
                data: $(this).serialize() + '?preco=' + preco,                        
                success: function (obj) {                            
                    if (obj.success == true) {
                        alert('evento salvo com sucesso');
                        $('#fecharCrEvento').click();
                        $('#calendario').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                    }
                    else {

                    }

                }
            }).
};
```

Comment: Assim que chegar em casa testarei o código e te aviso! (:

Comment: Mas no caso ele apenas checa se é valido ou já exibe os erros

Comment: Ele faz os dois, checa e exibe erros.